# How to append a CSS rule to the another CSS rule

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question. However, I couldn't find an answer after 10 minutes search. I would like to explain my question with examples, so you can understand what I am exactly talking about.

Let's say there is a div tag with an id and it has also some text inside:

```
<div id="text">Hello World</div>
```

and I also have css rule which will turn the text into red.

```
.makeRed{
   color: #FF0000;
}
```

The question is I want to make the text red in my div tag. I can simply do it like this:

```
<div id="text" class="makeRed">Hello World</div>
```

Instead of doing it, is there another way to make that text turn to red? Because if I keep adding makeRed rule to my every div that I need, it will turn my html into garbage. So I wonder if there is any way to do it clearly. I would like to use that way for "clearfix" method for some of my divs.

Whenever I need clearfix, I do like this and this is bad:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div id="text">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `.makeRed` signify?  Should `makeRed` be called something more semantic like `error-message`?  If you name your classes for what they mean not how they look you might end up with more descriptive and organized css/html.

Comment: No, that's specifically what classes are for, to define visual characteristics of html elements that share something in common in meaning (semantics). Unless you want every div to have red text (probably not) or you want to maintain a horrendous list of id selectors in your CSS file, or all of these divs are in a container element that you could style, then continue to use classes, and like others have said, make your class more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the ID of your div to your css like so:

```
.makeRed, #text{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

You can separate targets by commas to include multiple different elements in the style. This will maintain the styles applied to `.makeRed` and apply to your `#text` div.

Comment: looks like this is what I am looking for but it still doesn't work in the way you told me.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: which text do you want to make red, and why?

If you want the text of all your divs red, you can just write

```
div{ color: red; }
```

If it's just for, say, an error message, I would add the class 'error' rather than 'red'. That way, you can make the HTML more semantic. You still have to add a class, but it has more meaning:

```
.message.error { color: red; }
```